# FireMonkey AbsoluteOpacity issue

Tags: components, firemonkey

I defined a component as

```
tZText = class (tText)
...
property Enabled : Boolean read GetEnabled write SetEnabled;     
...
procedure tZText.SetEnabled (const aEnabled: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Enabled := aEnabled;
  case aEnabled of
        False : TextSettings.FontColor := fTextColors.TextColorDisabled;
        True  : TextSettings.FontColor := fTextColors.TextColorIdle    ;
  end;
end;
```

It is suppoused that the component will paint the text according to the state of the Enabled property.

However, I followed the execution throughout the primitive code and, at some time, it makes the assignment

```
FLayout.Opacity := AbsoluteOpacity;
```

where AbsoluteOpacity is 0,6..., hence the text is painted as if the component is always not enabled.

I can not figure out why or where AbsoluteOpacity took this value.

I appreciate any suggestion to solve this issue.

Notes

1 the component's parent is a TRectangle

2 the environment is not styled